# What is object?.method() What does '?' do here?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am familiar with the concept of null safety and know about the late modifier and the ! and ? operators.
e.g.

```
String? hello;
```

But what is `hello?.toUpperCase();`
What does the '?' operator do here?

Answer (score 1):

By adding ? after a type it marks that it's value could be null. For example, `String? hello;` is a String that its value can be null (`hello = null;`).

About ! it's used when a value could be null and you don't want to use it's value if it's null. For example, if you have `String? hello;` and need to use the value, Null Safety will require you to put ! after it, so it ensures that when it's used, it's not null, and if it is, it will throw an error. For example: `String imNotNull = hello!;`

Another way of handling null values is adding ?? after a (maybe) null value, and adding a non null value after it. For example `String imNotNull = hello ?? 'notNull';`

Answer (score -1):

its short hand for

```js
hello? hello.toUpperCase():""
```